# React redux saga multiple renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm new to react and I'm having an issue of multiple renders and I was just wondering if I'm doing this right, so I dispatched an action to get a note list, in my list component which looks like this for now :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function NoteList (props){


const [ noteList, updateNoteList ] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    updateNoteList(
        props.noteList.map(note => {
            return {...note, mode : 'title-mode'};
        })
    )
},[props.noteList])



console.log(noteList);
return (
    <div>

    Notes come here

    </div>
  )

}
```

this component is connected in another container class but that's irrelevant, so what happens is this component renders 4 times, two times without the useEffect hook and two more with it, what I want to achieve is I need to add an item in the object of each note (which is mode : title-mode) in a state for this component which works fine with this code, as to why I'm adding this mode in a state is that I want to change this inside the note array so I can change the view mode for each note , but this component renders 4 times as I mentioned, and in my head no way that this is the correct way to do this.

Please help if you have the time .

Comment: Why you don't render `props.noteList` directly without `useState` and `useEffect` ?

Comment: Because I want to add a new value to each note which is this view-mode

Comment: couldn't you add it while rendering ?

Comment: I don't want to just render it, I want it to be a state value for this component, so that when I change this view mode I get a re-render and change the view of the component

Comment: This approach is causing more re-rendering, could you provide a reduced working example ?

Comment: But anyway the `title-mode` property should be handled otherwise !

Comment: I honestly don't know how I can give you a working example since there is a lot of things, the whole redux things and the container for this component, you can easily reproduce this effect in any saga application you have, just add useEffect hook that updates the state and you will get four renders

Comment: I meant that you should show how `title-mode` is used so we could reason about it?

Comment: I haven't yet implemented a use for it since I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but in text on the displayed list on click of a list item I will update the state of this component for that specific note to something like " expanded-mode" and on the re-render I will expand this list item to show the contents of the note, hope that made sense, if you think I'm going a long way to achieve this please suggest !

Comment: I will prepare an example to show how to switch the display mode !

Comment: take a look at this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ritchie-e9n7t?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks a lot @LefiTarik that helped me a lot, you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could achieve the display of the notes list by making a display-mode state in the `<Note />` component it self so changing the mode won't affect other notes and this way we won't have extra re-renders, also using this approach will allow also modifying the note locally without dispatching it to the store then we could update the store at the end gaining in perfs.
So basically this is the approach ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ritchie-e9n7t?file=/src/App.js)):

```
const Note = ({ title, content }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ border: "1px solid", margin: 5 }}
      onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}
    >
      {!isExpanded ? (
        <div>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>{content}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  // this is the notes state, it could be coming from redux store so
  // we could interact with it (modifying it if we need)
  const [notes, setNotes] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, title: "note 1", content: "this is note 1" },
    { id: 2, title: "note 2", content: "this is note 2" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <Note key={note.id} {...note} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```